# Unknown part on WiFi switch

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

What is this part? I've googled the code on top and haven't found any datasheet. It's connected to the AC supply on a WiFi switch that I'm trying to repair  so I figure it's a rectifier, but it also has 3 pins on the other side.

[image: the picture of the part]

Comment: The 2 pin component at the bottom the PCB appears to have dry joints?

Comment: Yes I soldered those up and current is passing fine through them. It is the main chip that is receiving no current after being rectified/step-downed so I assumed it's this chip because all the diodes on-board are fine.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a [Bright Power Semiconductor](http://www.bpsemi.com/en/) buck regulator — maybe a discontinued or not-listed part, given that it doesn't appear on their site and datasheets can't be found, but there are several parts with similar part numbers, package, and markings on [this page](http://www.bpsemi.com/en/product.php?id=68&pid=2).

Your guess is as good as mine what the correct specs are for the 2905 without a datasheet, though.